# missing config files when compiling a php extension

Tags: php5, php

I do the phpize..
When I reach the ./configure It tells me it can fins the php-config   (`configure: error: Cannot find php-config. Please use --with-php-config=PATH`)
I assume it means a file named `php-config`
I do `./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/src/php5/php-5.3.5/scripts/  --enable-entities`
Which points to that file's directory, but still, I get same error.

Comment: How did PHP get installed on your system?

Comment: it was built from source. I am building the extension from within the source folder /usr/local/src/php5/php-5.3.5/ext/source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`php-config` is a shell script (executable program) that should be part of your PHP installation.  Normally this would be on your `$PATH`, but in your case it is not.

Locate the program, and specify its full path (e.g. `--with-php-config=/usr/local/apache/PHP/bin/php-config`) to resolve the error message.
If you do not know where the script is you can use the `locate` or `find` command to help you find it.

Comment: Beat me by seconds.  In this case, the full PATH is `/usr/local/src/php5/php-5.3.5/scripts/php-config` according to the post.